# Selecting a sub XML as string

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have following XML:

```
<Run id="1">
  <Servers>
    <Server id="1" fqdn="ENG-HSINGH">
      <Roles>
        <Role id="1" rootFolder="C:\DeleteMe"/>
      </Roles>
    </Server>
  </Servers>
  <Roles>
    <Role id="1">
      <ValidationInformation>
        <ValidationObject>
          <FileSystem>
            <Directory path="\A\HTML">
              <File id="1" path="\A\HTML\1.HTM"/>
              <File id="2" path="\A\HTML\2.ASP" />
            </Directory>
            <Directory path="\B\EntireFolder">
              <File id="8" path="\B\EntireFolder\1.txt"/>
              <File id="9" path="\B\EntireFolder\2.txt"/>
              <File id="10" path="\B\EntireFolder\3.txt"/>
              <File id="11" path="\B\EntireFolder\4.txt"/>
              <File id="12" path="\EHR\EntireFolder\5.txt"/>
            </Directory>
            <Files>
              <File id="4" path="\C\6.txt"/>
            </Files>
          </FileSystem>
        </ValidationObject>
      </ValidationInformation>
    </Role>
    <Role id="2">
      <ValidationInformation>
        <ValidationObject>
          <FileSystem>
            <Directory path="\D\HTML">
              <File id="13" path="\D\HTML\1.HTM"/>
            </Directory>
            <Directory path="\E">
              <File id="14" path="\E\1.txt"/>
            </Directory>
            <Files>
              <File id="15" path="\F\1.txt"/>
            </Files>
          </FileSystem>
        </ValidationObject>
      </ValidationInformation>
    </Role>
  </Roles>
</Run>
```

I want to read this XML into a dictionary representing Roles and it's corresponding ValidationInformation sub XML as string.e.g.

```
1, "&lt;ValidationObject&gt;&lt;FileSystem&gt;&lt;Directory path='\A\HTML'&gt;&lt;File id='1' path='\A\HTML\1.HTM'/&gt;&lt;File id='2' path='\A\HTML\2.ASP' /&gt;&lt;/Directory&gt;&lt;Directory path='\B\EntireFolder'&gt;&lt;File id='8' path='\B\EntireFolder\1.txt'/&gt;&lt;File id='9' path='\B\EntireFolder\2.txt'/&gt;&lt;File id='10' path='\B\EntireFolder\3.txt'/&gt;&lt;File id='11' path='\B\EntireFolder\4.txt'/&gt;&lt;File id='12' path='\EHR\EntireFolder\5.txt'/&gt;&lt;/Directory&gt;&lt;Files&gt;&lt;File id='4' path='\C\6.txt'/&gt;&lt;/Files&gt;&lt;/FileSystem&gt;&lt;/ValidationObject&gt;"

2, "&lt;ValidationObject&gt;&lt;FileSystem&gt;&lt;Directory path='\D\HTML'&gt;&lt;File id='13' path='\D\HTML\1.HTM'/&gt;&lt;/Directory&gt;&lt;Directory path='\E'&gt;&lt;File id='14' path='\E\1.txt'/&gt;&lt;/Directory&gt;&lt;Files&gt;&lt;File id='15' path='\F\1.txt'/&gt;&lt;/Files&gt;&lt;/FileSystem&gt;&lt;/ValidationObject&gt;"
```

I know I can read the XML nodes under ValidationInformation node for each role and stick the resultant XML, but that does not seem like a good way to do it.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Thanks,
H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(<myInputXMLAsString>);
            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Run/Roles");

            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                int roleId = int.Parse(xn["Role"].Attributes["id"].Value);
                XmlDocument subXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                subXmlDocument.LoadXml(xn.InnerXml);
                XmlNodeList subXn = subXmlDocument.SelectNodes("/Role/ValidationInformation");
                string validationInfo = subXn[0].InnerXml;
                roleIdToValidationInformationDictionary.Add(roleId, validationInfo);
            }
```