# access sub XML values in sms web service that hasnt value in standard way

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I have following xml :

in other standard xml like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24658359/308578) here we have no problem but in php web service :

http://sandoghche.com/WebService

for inbox check my inbox xml is this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>
<Result>
  <text_message>
    <id>509</id>
    <message><![CDATA[a]]></message>
    <time>1323519941</time>
    <message_phone>
      <cellphone>09196070718</cellphone>
    </message_phone>
  </text_message>
  <text_message>
    <id>507</id>
    <message>1</message>
    <time>1323519803</time>
    <message_phone>
      <cellphone>09360437392</cellphone>
    </message_phone>
  </text_message>
  <text_message>
    <id>303</id>
    <message><![CDATA[smsm text]]></message>
    <time>1318343296</time>
    <message_phone>
      <cellphone>09354338365</cellphone>
    </message_phone>
  </text_message>
  <text_message>
    <id>219</id>
    <message><![CDATA[my sms texts here]]></message>
    <time>1316154042</time>
    <message_phone>
      <cellphone>09127930265</cellphone>
    </message_phone>
  </text_message>
  <text_message>
    <id>217</id>
    <message>2</message>
    <time>1316090189</time>
    <message_phone>
      <cellphone>09195533234</cellphone>
    </message_phone>
  </text_message>
</Result>
```

for this I wrote the following code

```
public class SMSData
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public string message { set; get; }
    public string cellphone { set; get; }
}



  string data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><Result><text_message><id>509</id><message><![CDATA[a]]></message><time>1323519941</time><message_phone><cellphone>09196070718</cellphone></message_phone></text_message><text_message><id>507</id><message>1</message><time>1323519803</time><message_phone><cellphone>09360437392</cellphone></message_phone></text_message><text_message><id>303</id><message><![CDATA[ممنون.شما؟]]></message><time>1318343296</time><message_phone><cellphone>09354378365</cellphone></message_phone></text_message><text_message><id>219</id><message><![CDATA[سلام اقاي طباطبايي لينك مربوط به ورود اعضا به وبلاگ روي صفحه فيلتر مي رود با احترام احدي]]></message><time>1316154042</time><message_phone><cellphone>09127960265</cellphone></message_phone></text_message><text_message><id>217</id><message>2</message><time>1316090189</time><message_phone><cellphone>09195523234</cellphone></message_phone></text_message></Result>";

    Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(data);

    XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(s);

        while (xr.Read())
        {
            if ((xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xr.Name == "text_message"))
            {
                if (xr.HasValue)
                {
                    string id = xr.GetAttribute("id");
                    string message = xr.GetAttribute("message");
                }
            }
        }
```

and this code

```
    Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(data);
    XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Result");

    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
```

but can't catch values on this xml document.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: nice question, saber!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easier to use the built-in Serializers for these kind of things, like the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(v=vs.110).aspx). I used the latter and tested your XML with the following snippet.

First [annotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) your SMSData class and create a new class to hold the Message_phone elements in a new class:

```
[DataContract(Name="text_message",Namespace = "")]
public class SMSData
{
    [DataMember(Order =1)]
    public int id { set; get; }    
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string message { set; get; }
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public int time { set; get; }
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public Message_phone message_phone { set; get; }

     // for easy access to cellphone
        public string cellphone {
            get 
            {
                 return message_phone!=null?message_phone.cellphone:null;
            }
        }
}


[DataContract(Name="message_phone",Namespace = "")]
public class Message_phone
{
    [DataMember]
    public string cellphone { set; get; }
}
```

and then create an instance of the DataContractSerializer for your array of SMSData, and call [ReadObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms573849(v=vs.110).aspx) on it like so:

```
Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(data);

var ds = new DataContractSerializer(
               typeof(SMSData[]),   // array of SMSdata
               "Result",            // top level element
               "",                  // empty namespace
               new List<Type> { typeof(SMSData[])} );    

var smsdata = (SMSData[]) ds.ReadObject(XmlReader.Create(s));

// smsdata now holds the SMSData from the Xml file
```

Comment: text_message has 'time' field that i cant read/retrieve it ... can you  ...  help me?   .. when read it message_text and message and cellphone value returned null...  !!! why?

Comment: i do that     [DataMember]
    public int time { set; get; }  but others returned null !!!

Comment: Fixed it by adding an explicit Order on the SMSData type members